# Excel dates being read as string not float in python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Essentially, there is this application I'm working on which involves pulling dates from a table in an Excel file. I know that Excel stores dates as floats, so I would first get the `raw_date` (floating number) with this:

```
raw_date = worksheet.cell_value(i,0)
```

Before converting it using this line of code:

```
conv_date = datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(raw_date, workbook.datemode))
```

The issue I'm having is that when I would run my code, I would get this error.

```
if xldate < 0.00:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

So I checked around online to see what was causing this and someone said to check whether my `raw_date` is actually a float. I printed the `raw_date`, and it outputted the date itself instead of a decimal number and when I checked its type, python tells me it's a string. I made sure to double-check my Excel file and ensure that all the dates were in the Excel date formats but to make things more strange, I had an older Excel file that I was pulling dates from and when I did the same testing for those (print the `raw_date` and check type), it outputted decimal numbers and the type was float as expected. So I'm assuming the issue is to do with my new Excel file, but I can't pinpoint what exactly is causing the dates to be pulled as strings and not floats.

Edit:

I tried converting all the dates to numbers and noticed that only some would convert while the others remained the same. I then realized that the ones that didn't change would not convert into *any* number format.

[image]

Edit 2:
Below are some of the dates from the excel table. I copied the cell value.

18/12/2021
20/12/2021
31/12/2021

Comment: Okay, in your new Excel file. Are they string or are they actual dates? An easy way to tell is to use a `MONTH()` function and reference one of the dates. Another, is to simply format the dates back to numbers. If Excel tells you it can't, those were never valid dates to begin with. What then could be the problem, is the standard format for dates in your Excel. For example; times can be in 24 hours or AM/PM, MM/DD YYYY or  DD/MM YYYY  and even the decimal notation can differ (comma or dot). So it can be a multitude of different things. Please show us it!

Comment: @Chrimle I used the `MONTH()` function on the dates and it does return a month number for the dates so that is working.  I am not sure how to convert the dates back to numbers. And what do you need me to show? A screenshot of the date cells or their formatting. Thank you so far.

Comment: In Excel, dates are numbers. But once you import it into Python (in this case), it is perceived as a string. So, you could change the date into a number just to check if Python accepts it as a number. To make the conversion, select your dates, go to "Home" -> "Number". There's a drop down box that probably says "Date", change it into "Number". Now they should have turned into large numbers. Yeah, include a screenshot of some of the dates, maybe it can help us in some way? :)

Comment: @chrimle Alright. I edited my question and included a screenshot of the dates after I tried converting them into regular numbers. I noticed that only some of them did while the others, I found out, would not change formats at all.

Comment: Oh nice! Well, there's the problem most likely! Now, what you could do, is to check if those dates contain spaces `" "` or anything similar. Even better would be to copy one of these cells' value and paste here (that might lead to a picture, in that case, paste into notepad or something, then copy it again). Make sure to get all the content of the cells.

Comment: @chrimle Okay. While tinkering with the dates, I noticed that If I wrote, in an empty cell or even the same cell, the date in the format MM/DD/YYYY then excel recognises it as a date and I can also then convert it to a number and other formats. So my questions now is that , is there a setting in excel that's causing this and also why does it  recognize the first 12 days of December as proper dates and not the rest as well? I also copied one of the cell's value into my question in the latest edit